# Preston is giving me endless quest

Tags: fallout-4

I have done the mass fusion with the brotherhood and then went to the railroad to see how to beat the institute after i got banished then they told me to talk to the minutemen(Preston Garvey)but when i do that he either wants to be my companion or gives me never ending quest what do i do?

Comment: have you progressed the Minutemen story up to retaking the Castle?

Comment: According to Nukapedia, you need to have a certain number of minutemen settlements to progress to the [next quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Form_Ranks). Maybe you don't have enough yet.